# Making sure observables in for loop are all finished before executing other code

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
getPersons().subscribe(
    persons => {
        for (const person of persons) {
            getAddress(person.id).subscribe(
                address => {
                    person.address = address;
                }
            );
        }
        doSomethingWithAddresses();
     }
);
```

The problem is that doSomethingWithAddresses is executed before all the getAddress observables are finished. How can you make sure they are all finished before executing subsequent code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make use of RxJS's [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) to wait for the for..of loop to be completed before returning all the observables.

Here are the changes you should make to your code:

```
getPersons().subscribe(
  persons => {
    const observablesList = [];
    for (const person of persons) {
      const getAddressObservable = getAddress(person.id);
      observablesList.push(getAddressObservable)
    }
    forkJoin(observablesList).subscribe(response => {
      // console.log(response) to check that there is a list of returned observables
      const result = persons.map((person, index) => {
        person['address'] = response[index]['address'];
        return person;
      })
      doSomethingWithAddresses();
    })
  }
);
```

---

Alternatively, you may try this to prevent the chaining of `subscribe()`

```
getPersons().pipe(
  mergeMap(persons => {
    const observablesList = [];
    for (const person of persons) {
      const getAddressObservable = getAddress(person.id);
      observablesList.push(getAddressObservable)
    }
    return observablesList;
  })
).subscribe(response => {
  // console.log(response) to check that there is a list of returned observables
  const result = persons.map((person, index) => {
    person['address'] = response[index]['address'];
    return person;
  })
  doSomethingWithAddresses();
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the right approach, but I still need to assign each address to each person before doSomethingWithAddresses() is called. Is that possible with forkJoin?

Comment: @Spacejockey Actually, yes. When you subscribe to the observables from forkJoin, you will realise that it returns a list of returned values from the observables. In Pseudocode, you will get something like this `[addressObj1, addressObj2, addressObj3, etc, etc]`. From there, you can probably use Array.map() to map each element in the array to assign the address to each person! Let me try to add it to my answer so that it is more clearly illustrated.

Comment: Let me know if it works, I am going to add another alternative solution to make this cleaner, as I realise I am nesting subscribes here.

Comment: @wentjun hi, can you describe a bit why we are creating a observable list here? why not using another mergemap to get the address of the person??

Comment: @wentjun oh you get me wrong mate. actually I wanted to learn. I saw in some place that some use mergemap for these kind of scenario. but here you create a list of observable. I tried to understand the solution and asked that question

Comment: @SadidKhan Sorry about that, I didn't mean to sound harsh. TBH, I think there are a few ways to approach it, but my idea is to handle it 'chunk by chunk' and to separate the concerns. I thought it might be alright if we wait for the observables within the for..of loop to be completed, before moving on to the next set of operations. Therefore I decide to lump them together and return the observables when the for..of loops have been fully executed..! This is sort of a 'foolproof' way of ensuring that `doSomethingWithAddresses()` will be executed only after the for loops have been completed.

Answer (score 0):

```
let loadedPerson;
getPersons().pipe(
  mergeMap(persons => {
  return of(persons);
}),
mergeMap(person => {
  loadedPerson = person;
  return getAddresses(person.id);
}),
map((address) => {
  loadedPerson.address = address;
}),
tap(()=>{
  doSomethingWithAddresses();
})
).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
methodOne() {
getPersons().subscribe(
    persons => {
        for (const person of persons) {
            getAddress(person.id).subscribe(
                address => {
                    person.address = address;
                }
            );
        }
     }
);
}

async methodTwo() {
await methodOne();
doSomethingWithAddresses();
}
```

Comment: Since `methodOne()` isnt tracking its child subscriptions or returning anything, isnt `doSomethingWithAddresses()` going to run without waiting for them to complete?