# In Promise loop, how to wait on request response?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a loop that sends requests.

However, I would like to wait to receive the answer of the request before sending the next one. How can I proceed?

```
 private start(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      for (let j = 0, p = Promise.resolve(); j < count; j++) {
        p = p.then(_ => new Promise<null>(res =>
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (j === (count - 1)) {
              resolve();
            } else {
              this.http.get();
              res();
            }
          }, 1000)
        ));
      }
    });
  }
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: can you use async/await? the code will result much more readable...

Comment: Subscribe to the result of `http.get()` and trigger the next "loop" after that resolved instead of calling `res()` synchronously in the next line. However, it would be better to know what you're trying to achieve to suggest better alternatives, as this does't feel right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for helping everyone,
Finally, I wrote this depending on @Capricorn response

```
      private start(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      for (let j = 0, p = Promise.resolve(); j < 10; j++) {
        p = p.then(() => new Promise<null>((res) => {
          this.get().then(() => res());
        }));
      }
    });
  }

  private get(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        alert('hello');
        resolve();
      }, 3000);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is odd that you are using promises (instead of [observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables)), when you are already working with Angular.

Anyways, when it comes to iterating promises, you can make use of [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). We push the promises into a list, followed by resolving the promises only after all iterations of the for loop have been executed.

```
const promisesList = [];
for (let j = 0; j < count; j++) {
  promisesList.push(promise);
}
Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
  // handle the rest here
})
```

---

As @robert suggested, I will include an implementation of how we can solve the above using observables/[forkjoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html). You will need to import `forkJoin` from the rxjs package before using it.

Similar to Promises.all(), `forkJoin()` waits for the for loop to be completed before returning the observable values.

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

.
.
.

start() {
  const observablesList = [];
  const sendRequest = this.someService.someRequest(); // observable

  for (let j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    observablesList.push(sendRequest);
  }

  forkJoin(observablesList).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    //handle the rest
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample with observables (maybe with forkJoin)

Comment: @robert Sure, no problem. While waiting, maybe you can read this answer of mine first? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55686179/10959940 The first block of code has the example you need.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. With observables it looks more Angular-ish :-)

Answer (score 2):

you can try like this

```
async mainFunction () {
for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    await apiCallFunction();
    // other code 
}
}

apiCallFunction() {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.get().subscribe(resp => {
      resolve();
    });
 })
}
```

Comment: All my parent functions need to be async after

Comment: Yes, bcs we can use `await` inside the `async` function only.

Comment: if all the api call is not depend on each other then you can use rxJs `forkjoin` for the same

Comment: @Geek_KK glade to know it helps you :)