# Handle multiple subscribes at once

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I have an array of string where I would like to call an async function on each string. What is the standard way to go about doing this? I used a for loop but the subscribe never hit so it would seem using a for loop is incorrect.

This is what I currently have:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedNodes.length; i++) {
    this.fileSelectorService.fixPath(this.selectedNodes[i])
        .subscribe(res => {
            // This block never gets hit when using a for loop (but it does hit without the for loop)
            var fixedPath = res;
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making sure observables in for loop are all finished before executing other code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55686084/making-sure-observables-in-for-loop-are-all-finished-before-executing-other-code)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `forkJoin()` after mapping the strings to an array of observable like this:

```
const arrayOfObs$ = this.selectedNodes.map(s => this.fileSelectorService.fixPath(s));

forkJoin(arrayOfObs$)
      .subscribe(result => {
                //result will be an array of the response for this.fileSelectorService.fixPath(s)
                console.log(result);
                //Do whatever you want to do with this result
            });
```