# RxJS - Multiple Requests using forEach and waiting all to finish

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this case:

- First i call a service, and get a list of items. (Array of objects)
- For each item in this list, i call another service, and they all actually can be fired parallel.
- I have to wait for all the answers. When i have all the answers, i have a finally logic.

I now have sth like this without using RxJS properly:

```
this.service.readArray().subscribe((array: Object[]) => {
  if (array.length > 0) {
    array.forEach((item, index) => {

      this.service2.readItem(item.id)
        .subscribe(details => {
          item.details = details;
          // manually finally logic
          if (index === array.length - 1) { // if the last iteration
            ...
          }
        }, (response: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            ...
          // manually finally logic also for error part
          if (index === array.length - 1) { // if the last iteration
          ... 
          }
        });

    });
  } else {
    ... logic for no items in list
  }
}, (error) => {
  ...
});
```

How can i represent this in a Rxjs (5) statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making sure observables in for loop are all finished before executing other code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55686084/making-sure-observables-in-for-loop-are-all-finished-before-executing-other-code)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use forkJoin to wait for all the calls to get finished. Look like you are using rxjs 5 [as you mentioned in your question] so let's change the code like this [see the description in the code comments]:

```
this.service.readArray()
        .switchMap(array => {
          //lets map the array member to the respective observable
          const obs$ = array.map(item => {

             return this.service2.readItem(item.id)
                        .pipe(
                           catchError(err => {

                             //Do whatever you want to do with this error
                             //make sure to return an observable as per your logic. For this example, I am simply returning the err wrapped in an observable. Having catchError operator will gracefully handle the exception and make sure to emit the value as part of forkJoin.
                             return of(err);

                           })
                         )
          });
          //forkJoin will wait for all the readItem calls get finished.
          return forkJoin(obs$);
        })
        .subscribe((finalArray) => {
          //finalArray will be the array of object [an response of this.service2.readItem(item.id)]
          console.log(finalArray);
          //do whatever you want to do with the array
        });
```

**EDIT - As asked by OP - To get hold of the response of `readArray`**

```
this.service.readArray()
        .switchMap(array => {
          //lets map the array member to the respective observable
          const obs$ = array.map(item => {

             return this.service2.readItem(item.id)
                        .pipe(
                           catchError(err => {

                             //Do whatever you want to do with this error
                             //make sure to return an observable as per your logic. For this example, I am simply returning the err wrapped in an observable. Having catchError operator will gracefully handle the exception and make sure to emit the value as part of forkJoin.
                             return of(err);

                           })
                         )
          });
          //forkJoin will wait for all the readItem calls get finished.
          return forkJoin(obs$)
                  .pipe(
                    //return the original array along with joined using of
                    mergeMap((joined) => {
                      return of([array, joined]); 
                    })
                  );
        })
        .subscribe((finalArray) => {
          //finalArray will have readArray API response [i.e. array] at 0 index and on 1st index it will have joined array
          console.log(finalArray);
          //do whatever you want to do with the array
        });
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. one thing though, some readItem calls may return 404 (not found), and i have a logic to run in this case, do you know where/how i should impement this? and also i would like to know whether in this example the subscribe is called even some of the readItem calls returned 404? Or is it just called when all obs objects return success? Thank you!

Comment: @akcasoy See my edited answer. You can use `catchError` operator to gracefully handle the error. `subscribe` will be called even if few of the calls return 404.

Comment: thank you. as a last question, do u know how i can reach the "array" (the answer from the readArray function) within the subscribe block? I have a finally  logic about the array itself when all the "readItem" calls are finished. but somehow within the subscribe i cannot read the "array" object.

Answer (score 0):

i have a solution with the zip function as alternative version.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjszipmkx

```
init() {
   const myService = new MyService();

   myService.getList().subscribe((arr) => {
     let observables = arr.map(value => myService.update(value))
    const allObs$ = zip(...observables);
    allObs$.subscribe((result) => {
      console.log("zip", result);
    }, (error) => { console.log(error) })
  })
}
```