# Create Angular observable on forEach

Tags: angular, observable

I have a forEach statement in Angular as part of a service

```
doSomethingService(someString: string) {

myarray.forEach(element => {
  if (element.Name === someString) {
    if (element.Visible === true) {
      element.Visible = false;
    } else {
      element.Visible = true;
    }
  }

});

}
```

Essentially I want to make this observable so that when the forEach completes it returns to the caller and then the caller can do something with the results.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: consider using .map() instead if .forEach(). please provide more details, it's unclear what you want to do. there's no point creating fake async code from synchronous just to have observables

Comment: Why? That code above does not make any I/O calls and is not dependent on an I/O call so there should be no reason to make it an observable. Please add some more context like what it is you are trying to accomplish (why do you think you need an observable).

Comment: ...the reason I want to do it is because the code that calls it is using the "myarray" that is getting updated.  Sometimes when I call the "doSomethingService" it doesn't update the array (which is stored in a global singleton) before the calling code moves on and uses the values in "myarray" which are now out of sync.  I'd like to update "myarray" and make the calling code wait until the forEach finishes.

Comment: The calling code already waits because it is a synchronous method

Comment: @Funn_Bobby you can try doing something like what I did over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55686084/making-sure-observables-in-for-loop-are-all-finished-before-executing-other-code/55686179#55686179

Answer (score 0):

Use 'of' operator from rxjs to return an Observable and then you may subscribeto it.Below is sample code

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'practice';
  myarray: Sample[];

  doSomethingService(someString: string) {
    this.myarray.forEach(element => {
      if (element.name === someString) {
        if (element.visible === true) {
          element.visible = false;
        } else {
          element.visible = true;
        }
      }
    });
    return of(this.myarray);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myarray = [
      { name: 'foo', visible: false },
      { name: 'boo', visible: false }
    ];
    this.doSomethingService('foo').subscribe(val => {
      console.log(val);
    });
  }
}
export interface Sample {
  name: string;
  visible: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your data `myarray` into `Observable`, the you will be able to use all **[Reactive Programming RxJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming)** using `pipe` function, Operators Like map,filter,swichMap,...etc

```
myObservable: Observable<Element[]>;
  constructor() {
    this.myObservable = this.doSomethingService("Khaled");

    // usage
    this.myObservable.subscribe(elements => {
      console.log(elements); // print elements
    });
  }

  doSomethingService(someString: string): Observable<Element[]> {
    return of(this.fetchMyData()).pipe(
      map(elements => {
        elements.forEach(element => {
          if (element.name === someString) {
            if (element.visible === true) {
              element.visible = false;
            } else {
              element.visible = true;
            }
          }
        });
        return elements;
      })
    );
  }

  fetchMyData(): Element[] {
    return [{ name: "Khaled" }, { name: "Ahmed" }];
  }
```